# cakephp how to run failure test case only

Tags: testcase, cakephp-2.4

The question is quite straightforward. I'm following up the TDD principle, so basically I write controller test case first then functions. One controller action might have multiple test cases and some are passed but the one I'm writing is failed.

Usually I verify http://domain.com/proj/test.php in browser and see if there are any failed test cases. My question is "how can I explicitly run failed test case only?". I want to ignore those passed test cases and only focus failed ones.

If there is no such feature in cakephp 2.4 stable, how to implement? Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful! Can you be sure a "fix" won't break something else. Not running the tests that passed the first time around might not be such a good idea.

Comment: I know it might be risky to only run failed test cases, but if the failed test cases is independent and I want to refresh page and only test the failed ones for time sake